# rcurl web scraping timeout exits program

Tags: timeout, scrape, rcurl

I am using a loop and *`rcurl`* scrape data from multiple pages which seems to work fine at certain times but fails when there is a timeout due to the server not responding.

I am using a `timeout=30` which traps the timeout error however the program stops after the timeout.  I would like the program to continue to the next page when the timeout occurrs but cant figureout how to do this?

```
url = getCurlHandle(cookiefile = "", verbose = TRUE)
```

Here is the statement I am using that causes the timeout. I am happy to share the code if there is interest.

```
webpage = getURLContent(url, followlocation=TRUE, curl = curl,.opts=list( verbose = TRUE, timeout=90, maxredirs = 2))
```

woodwardjj